# Animals won't follow me

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have wheat but animals aren't following me. I don't know what version I have but I play on my iDevice. Can someone tell me how I can get animals into my barn?

Answer (score 5):

Wheat doesn't attract animals yet. Plus, wheat will have no point because you can't breed the animals. But to get animals in your barn you can put light in the barn and come night animals will be attracted to the light and come in there. And for chickens find a chicken egg bring it to your barn and you try to mine the ground. A chicken may or may not come out and if you are in creative just use spawn eggs. You can attract pigs with beetroots after you grow them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small area out of blocks and put light in there. It will take a while but animals will go in there because of the light. Animals are attracted to light.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to get animals in your barn.

You basically dig a hole down by two blocks and push then in it then lead them to your barn or house or whatever as you can't attract them with wheat or breed them, which is a shame because it would be a lot easier